How to set default microphone in raspberry pi 4B
I'm testing Real-time transcription on Raspberry Pi 4 with Whisper.cpp library.
I'm using reSpeaker 2-Mics Pi HAT microphone. I already installed the required libraried and microphone is recording the sound with this command:
arecord -D "plughw:2,0" -f S16_LE -r 16000 -d 5 -t wav test.wav

And I can play the recording with this command:
aplay -D "plughw:2,0" test.wav

I notice "plughw:2,0" is creating problem to test whisper streaming here as there is no flag to input "plughw:2,0" in this command:
./stream -m models/ggml-tiny.en.bin --step 4000 --length 8000 -c 0 -t 4 -ac 512

I tried to set default microphone in raspberry pi by creating a file .asoundrc at /home/pi location and write these lines to set "plughw:2,0" as default microphone:
pcm.!default {
  type asym
  capture.pcm "mic"
}
pcm.mic {
  type plug
  slave {
    pcm "hw:2,0"
  }
}

But this will not make the microphone as default and My whsiper stream is not trascribing anything, it keeps printing "you".
And the Recording does not play with this command: aplay test.wav (without -D "plughw:2,0") so It means the microphne is still not set to default. How to make this microphone as default. Please help.

You can check this: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=294546

I recommend trying to download pauvcontrol and pulseaudio.

Use arecord -l to get recording devices.

From this command, you should see something like below appear in the terminal.
The two things you need to pay attention to is the card number and the device number.


Here is an example
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 1: Microphone [Yeti Stereo Microphone], **device 0**: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

Once you have identified your microphone’s device numbers, proceed to the next step.
If nothing appears, then make sure you have plugged your device in properly.

Now, create a configuration file for Alsa
This configuration file will help the Alsa driver understand what device it should be using for capturing audio.
Begin modifying the file by running the following command.

nano /home/pi/.asoundrc


Within this file, enter the following text.
Make sure that you replace [card number] and [device number] with the values you retrieved in step 3 of this section.

pcm.!default {
  type asym
  capture.pcm "mic"
}
pcm.mic {
  type plug
  slave {
    pcm "hw:[card number],[device number]"
  }
}

Once done, save the file by pressing CTRL + X, followed by Y, then ENTER.
I hope this helps.

Hi, It looks like you shared your answer from this article, https://pimylifeup.com/raspberrypi-microphone/ . It does not help. This is not addressing my problem

Maybe pavucontrol will help

Maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47188528/how-to-set-default-microphone-on-raspberry-pi-3b-with-raspbian-stretch
